# conflict two persistence.xml

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I have conflict two persistence.xml file one of them server configuration with filter and other test configuration. When I run the test sometimes maven uses server jpa configuration and ignores test configuration. What is solution in this case

```
<build>
    <finalName>qwe</finalName>
    <filters>
        <filter>conf.prop</filter>
    </filters>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>conf</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: Good question. How are you setting up your test environment? I prevent this problem myself by setting up a different persistence unit entirely for the test environment, with a different name.

Comment: I just use IJIDEA13 with mvn plugin with standart options, I hope that there is cleaner solution

Comment: My solution is plenty clean and conflict-free. But you do not answer my question at all, I guess I have to be more specific. How in your tests are you setting up your testing environment? How is the persistence unit created? What database do you use? What additional tools do you use (selenium, etc.)?

Comment: @Gimby, it's a quite good solution until you have to use two persistence units in single environment.

Comment: @zxcf Depends on the answer to my question to which no reply is coming. I setup the persistence units programmatically in my test environment (including injecting them in beans) and so have 100% flexibility. I'm trying to figure out how mister OP is doing it to see what possibilities there are :/

Comment: persistence.xml in src/test/resources/WEB-INF, transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" mysql, eclipseLink. I just create factory Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pername"), I have not additional tools, junit4 only